# UIPickerView row text is hidden

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I believe I have followed the steps to implement a UIPickerView to display an array of strings. For some reason, the text from titleForRow is hidden. I seems like the picker view is getting the array count because I have the ability to scroll. I just can't get the list if names. I am using UIStoryboard and all outlets are connected. Any help would be appreciated.

```
extension SongPlayerViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return hertzArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return hertzArray[row]
}

//when user selects row
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        
    }
 }
  class SongPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
     
         let hertzArray = ["432Hz", "528Hz", "174Hz", "396Hz", "417Hz", "639Hz", "741Hz", "852Hz"]

         @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
         @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!

          //when view did load
          override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

              pickerView.dataSource = self
              pickerView.delegate = self
          
          }
     }
```

[image: Screenshot of bug]

Comment: pickerView.reloadAllComponents() in viewDidAppear I guess maybe it will work ? 
or check yourdata source and delegate connected to viewController

Comment: What's the height of the pickerView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem with the code you've posted.  I put it into a playground with a little bit of setup code and it works.  You should check your outlets in the nib file and check at runtime to ensure that the `pickerView` property is being assigned. As suggested in comments, check the dimensions of the picker using the view debugging tools

(https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)

Here's the Playground I was working with:

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

```
class SongPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    let hertzArray = ["432Hz", "528Hz", "174Hz", "396Hz", "417Hz", "639Hz", "741Hz", "852Hz"]

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func loadView() {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        self.pickerView = pickerView

        view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480))
        view.addSubview(pickerView)

        pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
    }
}


extension SongPlayerViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return hertzArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return hertzArray[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    }
}

let songController = SongPlayerViewController()
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = songController
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested my code this morning after posting this last night. It works after not changing a thing. If this problem continues, I will use the View Hierarchy Debugger.